# How to connect XBOX360 Elite to Logitech X-540 5.1 speakers

Tags: xbox-360

I need advice on how to best set up AV connections on my XBOX.

I have the following hardware:

- Console: XBOX 360 Elite
- Monitor: Samsung 2443BW over HDMI
- Speakers: Logitech X-540 5.1

I have connected the XBOX to monitor via HDMI. The problem is this monitor does not have audio signal pass-through, so I need another way of passing the audio signal to my speakers.

What would you recommend?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the setup guide, the X-540 looks to only have analog mini-jack inputs, and the XBox 360 only outputs 5.1 over HDMI or optical.  You would need a box that takes the HDMI or optical signal and spits out 5.1 over 3 mini-jacks.  I'm not even sure if the XBox will allow you to use the optical output while using HDMI, which would mean using component cables.

Having said all that, I can't find a converter box that would work for you.  If one even exists, it's not showing up in search results.

EDIT: Found [one thing](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/HDExpressPCIe?utm_source=CSE&utm_medium=PPC&utm_campaign=none&utm_term=HDExpressPCIe-HD_Express_HDMI_Tower&SID=-1&zmam=89202644&zmas=1&zmac=1&zmap=HDExpressPCIe) that might work, but it's $500.

Answer (score 1):

As @MBraedley said, the XBox 360 only outputs 5.1 over HDMI or optical, so what you need is to convert from that to the 3.5mm 5.1 channel audio line-in that your speakers need.  As @MBraedley mentioned, a converter box is very expensive; however, you should be able to find an audio/video receiver (also called a "home theater" receiver) that will take HDMI inputs and output the audio in different formats (i.e. output your audio to a 3.5mm and let you still use HDMI for video).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I had it connected to my AV receiver previously and just wanted to see if I can move XBOX to a different room in the house.